# Xilium.CefGlue demo project does not show up

Tags: 64-bit, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I'm trying to run demo project that comes with Xilium.CefGlue repository on Bitbucket.

When I run it, it goes into `Initialize()` method of `CefRuntime` class, and after(during) `libcef.initialize(n_main_args, n_settings, n_app)` program just stops.

I tried different version of `icudt.dll` and `libcef.dll` libraries for both x86 and x64 (actually I need x64). When there is library mismatch, exception is shown, but nothing shows up in my case.

I think, it's pretty elementary problem, but I've already spent a lot of time and still can't solve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you mean by just stop? It is throw exception or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the system log for errors.
2. Look into the commit logs of the current branch: you can see the version 'libcef' needed.
3. Check the application layout:http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/GeneralUsage#Application_Layout

P.S. All 64bit builds of CEF3 are marked as "experimental".

Comment: thanks, I checked `cef.log` and put `en-US.pak` of cef resources into `locales` folder of my application